# Angular 4.3.6 animations not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

After migrating from Angular 4.3.5 to 4.3.6 something with animations went bad (with 4.3.5 was everything alright).

The problem is that, when the application starts, the login component is loaded, and that component has `fadeIn` animation to show up. After upgrade to the latest angular version, my component is hidden always after the application is loaded. I inspected the login component and found that it has `style="display: none";` applied.

I am using external animations.ts file to store all my animations.

**animations.ts**

```js
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

// Fade In Animation
export const fadeIn = trigger('fadeIn', [
    transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(500, style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ])
]);
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

import { fadeIn } from './../../shared/animations/animations';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-authentication',
    templateUrl: './authentication.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./authentication.component.css'],
    animations: [fadeIn]
})

export class AuthenticationComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**login.component.html**

```js
<div class="container" [@fadeIn]>
    <div class="loginContainer">
        <div class="loginHeader">Login</div>
        <form name="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginForm.form.valid && logIn()" novalidate>
            <div class="loginBody">
                <span>content</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The strangest part is even if I remove `[@fadeIn]` from HTML, my component is loaded hidden. Only after I remove `animations: [fadeIn]`, from `login.component.ts`, then my login form shows up, just without any `fadeIn` animation.

NOTE: I am using `[@fadeIn]` without any expressions. But till 4.3.5 version it was working just fine.

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: did you try `@fadeIn` without the brackets on your container? `<div class="container" @fadeIn>`

Comment: already tried and no success

Comment: Hi Dance, Any news regarding this bug ? Same problem here if I edit the angular version : https://plnkr.co/edit/Uo1coU9i1GsB1I4U3809?p=preview

Comment: No news yet. actually waiting for next version release. But I've checked your plunker with versions 4.3.1 - 4.3.6. Seems only 4.3.3 is not working. The latest 4.3.6 is working well.

Comment: Really ? I have a bug using 4.3.6 ... See updated version : https://plnkr.co/edit/NPxUhgvRXbw2Kwdcq1H4?p=preview and try going to about, then back home :(

Comment: Plunker works if using 4.3.6 everywhere but keep 4.3.1 on @angular/animations/browser ... that's weird.

Comment: Yeah you are right. With 4.3.6 when i go back to Home from About page, Home page just disappear. I've inspected code and found that the problem is the same as in my case. The Home component got `display: none`

Inspected home component:
`<home _nghost-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-homeTransition ng-animate-queued" style="display: none;"></home>`

Comment: There's an open issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18923 which is probably the best place to stay updated on this regression status.

Comment: Seems Angular was updated to 4.1.1 and animation problems were fixed.
Also this plunk with 4.1.1 seems working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/NPxUhgvRXbw2Kwdcq1H4?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Angular seems to fix issues with animation after version 4.4.1. Updating to 4.4.1 should resolve the issue.

Comment: This was introduced in 4.3.6, and is a regression. Hopefully 4.3.7 will fix it.

Comment: @Dance: so in your answer, you meant 4.4.1 instead of 4.1.1?

Comment: @Bob yes Bob you are correct. I can't edit the post, because there was a mistake with 4.1.1. It should be 4.4.1 ;)